# What is the meaning of last statement in the following code segment?

Tags: java, inheritance, function-call

```
class X {                                     //Base class
    void do1() {
        System.out.println("do1");
    }
}

class Y extends X {                           //Derived class
    void do2() {
        System.out.println("do2");
    }
}

public class ass9 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {    //main class
        X x1 = new X();
        X x2 = new Y();
        Y y1 = new Y();
        ((Y) x2).do2();                        //What does this mean?
    }
}
```

The output is : `do2`

I am not understanding the way last statement is being executed.May be there is some concept of preference of ')' and '.' operators, but still, am not getting it.

Comment: Please see the section Casting Object [Java Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Comment: Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html, especially the "Casting" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the superclass does not have access to the methods of the subclasses, you need an explicit cast to call it.

We know that `x2` is a `Y` and by definition a `X` since `Y` extends `X`.

But the reference we're using to handling the `x2` is a `X` reference so it doesn't have, like said earlier, access to new methods and fields within `Y`.

To fix that, we need to *transform* the reference which is an `X` to a `Y`.

Answer (score 3):

The `Y` class extends the `X`, class, but `x2` can only be referred to as an `X`, and not a `Y` from `X x2 = new Y()`, so `Y` methods can't be called.

`(Y) x2` will cast `x2` to a `Y` so `Y` methods can be called.

`(Y x2).do2()` simply calls the `do2` method of the `Y` class for the `x2` object.

You could also do the same like so

```
Y x3 = (Y) x2;
x3.do2();
```

You can read more about subclassing and casting [from this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Comment: got it.it was just a simple case of casting.thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

It is casting the object "x2" to type "Y" so that it can do the "do2()" function that only objects of type Y can execute. The parentheses around the (Y) are to tell it is a cast, and then wrapping all of that into parentheses like ((Y) x2) is treating it as an object that you can then execute the method on. I would comment this, but I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a class name in parenthesis (as is done by `(Y)`) is called casting. It tells the compiler to ignore the type of the variable and assume that the variable is of the type you specified.

Comment: It doesn't really "ignore" the type: if the cast is impossible (like casting a String to an Integer, for example), the compiler will refuse to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Variable x2 is casted to type Y, then call `do2()` of type Y

Without cast is of type X, and type X has no method `do2();`

real but hidden value is Y type, so this is legal. If this assumption could be not correct then `ClassCastexception` is thrown